# Searching Words with specific conditions with grep

Tags: grep

As a school exercise I have to find from a file the specific words that :
Start the line and the first letter Is C, the next letter is a vowel and at last the 3rd letter must be consonant. The word must have only 3 letters

This one must be "solved" using grep but also other solutions are welcome

```
grep -E "^C[aeiouAEIOU]….." ./myfile.txt
```

I don't know how to find the 3rd letter . The consonanat

Comment: The same way you match a vowel, just with more characters?

Comment: And use `$` to match the end of the line after the third character.

Comment: FYI, you can use `-i` to make it case-insensitive, so you don't have to put both upper and lowercase letters in the character sets.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a shortcut. Rather just add all the alphabet twice

Comment: Be careful, if you use `-i`, you can no longer guarantee the first letter is `'C'` (could be `'c'`). Best to just include all consonants in a second `[bcdfg..]$` (followed by the dollar sign to make explicit nothing else follows)

Comment: Using `$` would only match if the word is the entire line -- if its just the first word on a line with multiple words, it won't match.  That may or may not be what you want; its not clear from the problem statement.